# How to use Wi-Fi adapter in virtual machine as Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

How to use Wi-Fi adapter in virtual machine as Wi-Fi adapter? I don't want to connect some network before. I want to connect to wi-fi network in my virtual machine. No matter what it will be - client or server virtualization. Of course server virtualization will be preferred (hyper-v/kvm) but any solution will be good. Any of current solution is telling that I need to connect to network on host machine. I need to connect on guest machine NOT HOST! Also this is not duplicate question because I was searched for it before!

ps. why I need this? i don't want install linux on bare hardware but want to use wi-fi adapter in virtual machine for actions like - capture wifi packets and other things that can do wifi adapter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign an INTERNAL Wifi Adapter to the guest OS in VM?](http://superuser.com/questions/421173/how-to-assign-an-internal-wifi-adapter-to-the-guest-os-in-vm)

Comment: techie007 this article not telling how to use wifi as wifi. it just telling that client virtualization have no direct access to hardware. okay. then how to use server virtualization like kvm/hyper-v/xen and others to have wifi adapter as wifi adapter. the topic says it all!

Comment: This can be done with a USB WiFi adapter. It won't work for other kinds of WiFi adapters because there's no point at which the line can be drawn between the guest and the host. (The USB interface provides such a line.)

Comment: asnwer can be marked as solved for client solution. for hyper-v this cannot be done because no usb passthrough. didn't test it with kvm because have no linux server at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that, during installation any hypervisor makes a virtual interface (for VMware vmnet0=bridge, vmnet2=host only and vmnet8=NAT rest for custom LAN segments) I assume, you want to use it for KALI "airmon" purpose. I work with VM architectures and I can assure you the traffic that gets translated into these VM networks from your physical interface gets an L2 ethernet encapsulation, the headers aren't 802.11x and it makes the whole mess, hence even if you try to bridge it won't even work. I wish developers make a secondary encapsulation provision in future but no hypervisor as of now does this.

You may wanna use a USB wifi stick (but make sure it supports monitor modes), or boot the KALI from and USB.

you may also wanna use "Compat-Wireless 2.6" but it just simulates an interface doesn't do monitoring.

Comment: Can you perhaps correct some of the formatting and punctuation to make this a little more clear? It seems like a good answer, but it is difficult to comprehend in its current form.